# Should i index columns separately or in groups?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

assuming a table structure as below, i would like to know if it is best to index columns separately or in group:

```
tbl_id | column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column 5
---------------------------------------------------------
1      | 'aaa'   | 'bbb'   | 'ccc'   | 'ddd'   | 'eee'
2      | 'bbb'   | 'ccc'   | 'ddd'   | 'eee'   | 'fff'
3      | 'ccc'   | 'ddd'   | 'eee'   | 'fff'   | 'ggg'
4      | 'ddd'   | 'eee'   | 'fff'   | 'ggg'   | 'hhh'
5      | 'eee'   | 'fff'   | 'ggg'   | 'hhh'   | 'iii'
```

there comes to a point that i may use `column1`, `column2`, and `column3` all together in a where statement (`WHERE column1 = 'val' AND column2 = 'val' AND column3 = 'val'` or `WHERE CONCAT(column1, ' ', column2, ' ', column3) = 'val val val'` <= i think this is rather impractical). in special cases, i might also use `column4` in conjunction with the first 3 columns.

so my question would be:

1. Should i index the 4 of them all together?

   > CREATE INDEX index_name ON tbl (column1, column2, column3, column4) `...` ;
2. Should i index the first 3 columns, then the fourth separately?

   > CREATE INDEX index_name_1 ON tbl (column1, column2, column3) `...` ;
   >
   > CREATE INDEX index_name_2 ON tbl (column4) `...` ;
3. Should i index all 4 of them separately?

   > CREATE INDEX index_name_1 ON tbl (column1) `...` ;
   >
   > CREATE INDEX index_name_2 ON tbl (column2) `...` ;
   >
   > CREATE INDEX index_name_3 ON tbl (column3) `...` ;
   >
   > CREATE INDEX index_name_4 ON tbl (column4) `...` ;
4. Should i index them in group, then separately?

   > CREATE INDEX index_name ON tbl (column1, column2, column3, column4) `...` ;
   >
   > CREATE INDEX index_name_1 ON tbl (column1) `...` ;
   >
   > CREATE INDEX index_name_2 ON tbl (column2) `...` ;
   >
   > CREATE INDEX index_name_3 ON tbl (column3) `...` ;
   >
   > CREATE INDEX index_name_4 ON tbl (column4) `...` ;

My understanding is that, if i am to separately index them, it would be extremely useful in cases that they would individually be searched/joined with (i.e.: `WHERE column1 = 'val'`). Hopefully i can clear my knowledge with indexes on this, thanks.

Comment: You create indexes based on exact queries you run against the table. There is no universal recipe on what indexes you create unless you analyse all the queries you want to optimise.

Comment: but if i have multiple queries with just different set of fields in the `WHERE` clause, wouldn't that mean i'd have to have many indexes?

Comment: As I said - there is no general advice. Every case should be analysed specifically. You have multiple queries - you need to optimise your table structure according each of them. Would you have many indexes? Who knows, provide the exact table structure and every exact query.

Comment: This is too vague.  If a column is a 2-state flag versus a nearly-unique name versus a date versus ... -- different guidelines _may_ apply.  If you ever do `>` or `IN` instead of `=`, different guidelines _will_ apply.  See my [_cookbook_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) for most of the answers.

Answer (score 2):

You should express the condition as:

```
WHERE column1 = 'val' AND column2 = 'val' AND column3 = 'val'
```

The appropriate index is a composite index on `(column1, column2, column3)`.  The order of these three columns in the index is not important.  You can add `column4` as the final key in the index.

If you use the `concat()` function, then MySQL cannot take advantage of any of the indexes that you suggest.

Comment: if i'm not mistaken, i'll only be separating `column4` as it varies from time to time that i'll be using it. correct?

Comment: @Nii - What do you mean "varies"?  Sometimes it is `column5`?  If so, then stick with the 3 columns and hope that it works well enough.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html - if you put a single index on column1 and column2 and column3 and column4 combined, any query using either column1 or (columns 1, and 2) or (columns 1, 2, and 3) or (columns 1, 2, 3, and 4) can use this index. So, by choosing option 4, no seperate index on column1 is needed

Comment: so it basically specifies that, if a certain column has already been indexed (by group) - we need not to index them individually? however, option 4 is to do index in both ways (in group and separately)

Comment: Yes, it does, and this is used from first indexed column ongoing. If you use a group index and try to use it for any query that does not contain the first column, it cannot be used. So, a group index for (colA, colB) is not used when only searching in colB; another group index for (colA, colB, colC) is not used when searching in (colB, colC), (colB), or (colC) only

Answer (score 1):

Suggest choose option 4, but if you query `WHERE column1 = 'val'` then the index on `column1` is duplicated because of the leftmost principle, actually `index_name` will be used; but if you query `WHERE column1 = 'val' AND tbl_id = 'val'` then index on `column1` is necessary. At last, don't create too many indexes on a table, this will cause write performance issue.

Comment: sorry, but can you explain it again? i forgot that all index names are `index_name_2`. hehe.

Comment: edited, sorry, previously `index_name_2` meant index on `column1`